# Has anyone used Complex Analysis in the Spirit of Lipman Bers as their textbook?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have free access to many Springer books from my library, which includes *Complex Analysis In the Spirit of Lipman Bers*. From what I've seen, it's a decent book that introduces the subject. Unfortunately, when I get a book for self study, I have a difficult time selecting exercises and end up doing them all.

What I'm asking is: Does anyone have a list of questions assigned as homework from this book? I think it would be wiser to do problems that are selected from an expert in the field.

Comment: Whats wrong with doing them all?